# How to get 'dueDate' object from Google Classroom API

Tags: python, rest, google-classroom

I've started learning python recently and I've wanted to use the Classroom API to learn about API's. I am able to print the list of all my courses and courseworks just like in the Quickstart, but I seem to not understand why I can't access objects like 'dueDate' and 'materials'. It gives me the error KeyError: 'dueDate' when I execute the code below after creating my authentication token:

```
service=build('classroom', 'v1', credentials=cred) 
results2 = service.courses().courseWork().list(courseId=courseid).execute() 
assignments = results2.get('courseWork', [])

for assignment in assignments:
     print(assignment['dueDate'])
```

Meanwhile, the code below seems to work just fine:

```
results2=service.courses().courseWork().list(courseId=courseid).execute() 
assignments=results2.get('courseWork',[])
    
for assignment in assignments:
    print(assignment['title'])
    print(assignment['state'])
```

Any idea on what I should be doing here? What should I change/add to my line of code? I'm quite new to this coding thing so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As google documented, dueDate is an optional field in courses.courseWork which means that maybe it is not set for your course list. The KeyError also points to this case because python KeyError basically raised when you try to access a key that isn’t in a dictionary (dict). See: https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork and for KeyError pls see eg.: https://realpython.com/python-keyerror/

Comment: `dueTime` is required when setting `dueDate`, ([ref](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork#Date)) are you making sure to set this?